# Stack Exchange Etiquette - Changing an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette, unaccepted-answer

If I accept a correct answer but a more detailed and clearer answer comes along after the fact, should I change the accepted answer?  Is it considered rude to the original answerer whose answer was correct?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156897/192187

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should accept whatever answer you feels best helped you solve your problem or answer your question, regardless of when it was posted.  Changing your accepted answer is perfectly fine if another answer has helped you more since you accepted another answer.